# Python: recursive creation of objects

Tags: python, recursion

I want to create variables whose type is of the same class in which they are declared:

```
Class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = C()
```

It's not working, is there some trick to make this work?

Comment: Can you explain why you would need to do this?

Comment: @Blender My class is a red-black tree that has two subtrees (themselves red-black trees) and I want to set them to nil red-black trees.

Comment: This will work, the same as any recursive function, you need to place a stopping condition, while here you aren't placing any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not use static typing, so there is no need to do something special for references inside a class to objects of the same type.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, left=None, right=None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

leaf1 = Node()
leaf2 = Node()
parent = Node(leaf1, leaf2)
```

Comment: I have updated the example to match a tree-structure more closely. Is it clear now?

Comment: Exactly what I needed ;) I don't understand why people have to wonder why should I need for like if it's known worldwide that such things are not to be done!

Comment: When people ask you why you need such and such a feature, it is mostly because it is not clear what you are trying to do. It was not clear to me what you were trying to achieve until you mentioned red-black trees.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might  be to use a getter, which creates the variable when you need it.

```
Class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = None

    def get_v(self):
        if self.v == None:
            self.v = C()
        return self.v
```

*Update:* This will extend the chain of instances of C with a new instance as needed, lazily creating an 'infinite' chain of Cs. However, since it turned out that the original question was aiming for red-black trees, this solution will not work, as it would extend nil-trees (leafs) to tree nodes when they are accessed.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer, as it will not help with OP's problem, which is to create a red-black tree. The leaf nodes are supposed to be None.

Comment: @HansThen That's why I said it *might* be a solution. That bit about the red-black trees wasn't there yet when I wrote this, and the original question sounded like the variable should be set for *every* instance.

Comment: you are right. It was not meant to imply that your answer was wrong. However, the answer can be confusing for people following the thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can't you'll get an infinite loop if you do that.

**EDIT**:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, member):
        self.v = member

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = C(None)
    b = C(a)
```

First instance will need a bogus parameter for this version to work but like I said in the comment I don't see why you'd want to do this.

Comment: Yes, so there is no way of making variables of the same class inside that class?

Comment: There is, just not like this. You need to pass a variable to the `__init__` method.

Comment: @HansThen Like calling `__init__` recursively?

Comment: No, I have written an answer to clarify using a code example.

Comment: The only way it could be partially doable is if you passed the C object as a parameter to the constructor. The problem being that the first one you'll create will need a bogus value. But really I don't see why you'd want to do that.

Comment: @Borgleader I have a redblack tree class in which the left and right redblack subtrees need to be initialized to a nil redblack tree!

Comment: @Borgleader OP wants to create a red-black tree. So leaf-nodes in this tree will have left and right subtrees with value None.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. But yeah you can't do it recursively because you'd create an object and initialize it's parameter which creates an object and initializes it's parameter which creates an object... you see where I'm going with this.

Comment: You seem to be repeating yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you are really describing is some form of a linked list. You can do this like so:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = None

object_1 = C()
object_2 = C()
object_1.v = object_2
```

The reason what you are doing is not working is because, the only thing you have told `C` to do is set one public data member to C. Thus, you get an infinite loop since that is all C knows how to do, illustrated below:

```
C's Procedure: When C is made, set a data member to a new C object
```

(then when it's run you get something like this)

```
object = C()
# -> Object.v = C() <-c2
# --> c2.v = C() <-c3
# ---> c3.v = C() <- c4
# ....
# ....->cInfinity.v = c()
```

So, setting `v` to none, makes the following happen.

```
object_1 = C()
# -> object_1.v = None
object_2 = C()
# -> object_2.v = None

object_1.v = object_2
# -> object_1.v = object_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with a defaultdict, where you initialize it to the Classname.

```
class Directory(defaultdict):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(Directory)
```

For example this will give you a dictionary with one sublevel of dictionaries. You could use this with your Node object.